# Best practice for debugging queries involving multiple nested dervied tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that is heavily  using multiple level of nested dervied tables. I am just wondering what is the best method of debugging this type of queries where you can look into what is coming from the inner derived tables etc? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, I'll at least temporarily pull those derived tables out into a table variable or temp table so I can get a better look at what's going on.

So, in an over-simplified example:

```
select *
    from table_a
        inner join (select * from table_b) b
        ...
```

would become

```
select * 
    into #tempb
    from table_b

select * from #tempb /* for debugging purposes */

select *
    from table_a
        inner join #tempb b
        ...
```

Comment: That's what i do too; was just curious if any of the debugging features within sql server could be better used in this type of scenario